# Functions: If $f(g(x))$ is onto, does this mean $g(x)$ is onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Question: Let $g:A \to B$ and $f:B \to C$ be two functions.
If $f$ and $f \circ g$ are onto, is $g$ necessarily onto?

I know it's not, but I don't understand why/don't know how to explain it.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

A simple counterexample on $\mathbb{Z}$ is $f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor$ and $g(x)=2x$. $g(x)$ is never an odd number, yet $f\circ g(x)=x$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, let $A=\{x\}$, $B=\{y,z\}$, $C=\{w\}$. $g(x)=y$, $f(y)=w$ and $f(z)=w$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example: let $C = \{c\}$ consist of one element. Define $f$ in the only way you can: $f(x) = c$ for all $x\in B$. Choose any $b\in B$, and define $g:A\to B:a\mapsto b$ for all $a\in A$. Then clearly both $f$ and $f\circ g$ are onto, but if $B$ has more than one element, $g$ is not.

Comment: It makes sense. So it can be, but not necessarily.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It really depends on the sets and the functions.

Answer (score 0):

To explain it, you need only exhibit an example in which $f$ and $f\circ g$ are onto, but $g$ is not.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
a&\rightarrow&b_0&\rightarrow&c\\
&&&\nearrow\\
&&b_1
\end{array}$$